# How to use special characters while joining tables using ilike or like in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-like

I have following tables in postgres:

```
TABLE1:

col1        col2
NCT03009058 nivolumab (opdivo)  
NCT03009059 pembrolizumab (keytruda)
NCT03009060 zumab
NCT03009061 pembrolizumab-keytruda
```

```
TABLE2:

col1    col2      
1   nivolumab
2   opdivo
2   pembrolizumab
3   keytruda
3   zumab
4   pembrolizumab
3   keytruda
5   0.4% lidocaine hydrochloride and 5% dextrose injection
```

I would like to join above tables on col2 but the 'like' and 'ilike' are ignoring the rows where there are special characters. I would like to use combination of special characters while joining like  '|;|-|/|(|)' How can I achieve below results?

The desired output is:

```
col1        col2                          col3
NCT03009058 nivolumab (opdivo)        nivolumab 
NCT03009058 nivolumab (opdivo)        opdivo
NCT03009059 pembrolizumab (keytruda)  keytruda
NCT03009059 pembrolizumab (keytruda)  pembrolizumab 
NCT03009060 zumab                     zumab
NCT03009061 pembrolizumab-keytruda    keytruda
NCT03009061 pembrolizumab-keytruda    pembrolizumab
```

Any suggestions here would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have something close with:

```
select * 
from table1 join table2
on to_tsvector(table1.col2) @@ to_tsquery(table2.col2);
    col1     |           col2           | col1 |     col2      
-------------+--------------------------+------+---------------
 NCT03009058 | nivolumab (opdivo)       |    1 | nivolumab
 NCT03009058 | nivolumab (opdivo)       |    2 | opdivo
 NCT03009059 | pembrolizumab (keytruda) |    3 | pembrolizumab
 NCT03009061 | pembrolizumab-keytruda   |    3 | pembrolizumab
 NCT03009060 | zumab                    |    3 | zumab
 NCT03009059 | pembrolizumab (keytruda) |    3 | keytruda
 NCT03009061 | pembrolizumab-keytruda   |    3 | keytruda
 NCT03009059 | pembrolizumab (keytruda) |    4 | pembrolizumab
 NCT03009061 | pembrolizumab-keytruda   |    4 | pembrolizumab
(9 rows)
```

Comment: The looks good but it is not taking other characters like '%'.. The table has more rows with other special characters. Can i add additional characters in this query?

Comment: This is using full text search to do some pattern matching that generally ignores special characters. I am not sure you can % as in LIKE but you can use something like `ts_tsquery(prefix:*')` which should do prefix pattern matching: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-controls.html

Comment: The query looks perfect but I am still getting the error: ERROR: syntax error in tsquery: "0.4% lidocaine hydrochloride and 5% dextrose injection"

Comment: I cannot reproduce please post corresponding data in table1 and table2.

Comment: @rshar Your example data needs to include an example of the problem you are having.

Comment: I have edited the table. Now when I am joining my table using ``` select * 
from table_1 join table_2 on to_tsvector(table1.col2)  @@ to_tsquery (table2.col2)
where table1.col2 ilike '%pembrolizumab%'

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=310f4ccceafff62d59bc9e9a7ccf081d

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution to this issue.. Instead of using to_tsquery, I used plainto_tsquery and it worked!!